# How do I determine what device my DVD drive is mapped to?

Tags: cd-drive

Sometimes my CD-ROM is mapped to /dev/sg0 and sometimes to /dev/sg1. How do I detect the currently mapped device in a bash script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the cdrom is already mounted (it normally mounts automatically when a CD is inserted), just run the following command:

```
mount | grep ^'/dev/sg' | awk '{print $1}'
```